# 4 bit ripple carry counter not working when i increased the clock division

Tags: verilog

When I increased the clk div for D flip flop, I m only getting output on q1, only q1 is blinking. Counter is not counting..

If directly clock is used without any division, that in all four q1,q2,q3 and q4, i will see the output, but it's too faster so can't able to differentiate counting..

Where is wrong here?

(I m checking this on xilinx sparten6 (mini) fpga onboard led )

```
ripple_carry_counter.v
-------------------------------------------------
module ripple_carry_counter(q,clk,reset);
output [3:0]q;
input clk,reset;
T_FF tff0(q[0],clk,reset);
T_FF tff1(q[1],q[0],reset);
T_FF tff2(q[2],q[1],reset);
T_FF tff3(q[3],q[2],reset);
endmodule

T_FF.v
---------------------------------------
module T_FF(q,clk,reset);
output q;
input clk,reset;
wire d;
D_FF dff0(q,d,clk,reset);
not n1(d,q);
endmodule

D_FF.v
--------------------------------------
module D_FF(q, d, clk, reset);
input d,clk,reset;
output q;
reg q;
reg[22:0]clk_div;
always @(posedge clk)
    clk_div <= clk_div + 1;
assign div = clk_div[22];
always @(posedge reset or posedge div)
    begin
     if(reset)
         q <= 1'b0;
    else
         q <= d ;
     end
endmodule
```

Comment: Actually I m not checking on simulation, I m checking on board using ISE tool

Comment: you should start with simulation. clk_div[22] is 2^23 clock cycles -- isn't it to much?

Comment: It's not clock, it's clock division to reduce the clock.. Cloc frequency is 12MHz, so i reduced that using intermidiate clock division

Comment: Serge means, your 12MHz input clock for `tff0` is divided by 2^23 first, which gets a ~1.43Hz internal clock before driving the 1st stage T flip-flop. That T flip-flop output again gets divided before clocking the 2nd stage T flip-flop.

Comment: yes..so  each d flip flop is getting 1.43Hz clock.. So it has to changing counting from 1,2,3,4,....15 every 1/1.43 sec. But It's just toggling only the q0 led..It's not counting

Comment: @RohitDH no, your design is not a one-clock system. The output `q[*]` of each `tff*` is used as the clock of next `tff*`.

Comment: yes, its asynchronous, But for the starting flip flop, it's driven by divided clock pulse . I m equalizing q <=d so that in every t flip flop, it gets the input from the output of previous flip flop. So i have to get counting.. But it's just toggling q0 only, q1,q2,q3 are not toggling. q1,q2,q3 are off always

Comment: @RohitDH The `tff0` T flip-flop works as you expected. But each succeeding T flip-flop is clocked by the previous T flip-flop's output, so it'll take much longer for them to update. And each T flip-flop gets input from the inverted version of its own output, not of previous flip-flop, thus forming a T flip-flop. It's not encouraged to chat much in the comment, you can check the schematic or the simulated waveform.